# How to Create tr and th of an HTML table

Tags: jquery, html-table, append

I am trying to make a table using jquery that should have following HTML

```
<table id="tblProviders">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Time (Sec.)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I have an array of string `columnKeys` that contain Column Names for `th` elements. I already have a table element. I want to attach `thead` and the rest of the elements using jquery.

```
<table id="tblProviders">

</table>
```

I tried following jquery but didn't work. Can anybody pls help me out to construct the table elements?

```
var tr = $("#tblProviders").append("tr");
for(var i =0; i< columnKeys.length; i++)
{
    var th = $("#tblProviders").append("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
    th.innerHTML = columnKeys[i];
    tr.append(th);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var $toAttach = $("<thead><tr></tr></thead>");

for (var i = 0; i < columnKeys.length; i++) {
  var $thead = $("<th></th>");
  $thead.text(columnKeys[i]);
  $toAttach.find("tr").append($thead);
}

$("#tblProviders").append($toAttach);
```

And as per your code, i think you are doing append() wrong and mixing JQuery and JavaScript which can lead to some confusion as JavaScript will not work as expected on some JQuery Objects.

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the code like below.

```
var columnKeys = ['Test1', 'Test2', 'Test3'];
var th = "";
for(var i =0; i< columnKeys.length; i++)
{
    th += '<th>' + columnKeys[i] + '</th>';      // TABLE HEADER.
}
 var tr = $("<tr>").append($(th));
 $("#tblProviders").append($(tr));
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/me6hj1fp/11/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/me6hj1fp/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/me6hj1fp/)

```
var columnKeys=["Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"];
var html="<tr>";
for(var i =0; i< columnKeys.length; i++)
{
    html+="<th>"+columnKeys[i]+"</th>";
}

html+="</tr>";
$("#tblProviders").append($(html));
```

Comment: There is one issue, when I populate table with data, the header rows disappear

Comment: How you populate table data?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [jQuery( html, attributes)](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to create DOM elements

```
//Create ROW
var tr = $("<tr>");
for (var i = 0; i < columnKeys.length; i++) {
    //Create HEADER
    var th = $("<th>", {
        html: columnKeys[i]
    });

    //APPEND IT TO ROW
    tr.append(th);
}

$("#tblProviders").append(tr);
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/2wo85rnn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using core JS code -

```
<table id="tblProviders">

</table>

var columnKeys=["Field1","Field2","Field3","Field4"];
var table = document.getElementById("tblProviders");
var tr_head = document.createElement("tr");
for(var i =0; i< columnKeys.length; i++)
{
    var th_i = document.createElement("th");
    var th_txt_i = document.createTextNode(columnKeys[i]);
    th_i.appendChild(th_txt_i);
    tr_head.appendChild(th_i);
}
table.appendChild(tr_head);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/me6hj1fp/10/